# C# Window Service not invoking timer function

Tags: c#, windows-services, system.timers.timer

In my Window Service application the timer function is never called. I deployed the service on my machine and then attached the service to Visual Studio with breakpoints on different function. After `OnStart()` none of my functions are called.

Here's my `OnStart()` function

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    this.timer = new System.Timers.Timer(50000);
    this.timer.AutoReset = true;
    this.timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
    this.timer.Start();
}
```

**Updated 09/12/2017 : Added Event log in try and catch**
This function then calls `timer1_tick()`:

```
 private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     try
     {
         EventLog.WriteEntry("Running.."+ e.ToString());
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         EventLog.WriteEntry("Caught Exception "+ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
     }
 }
```

The `timer1_tick` is never called. Any suggestions?

**Update 12/09/2017** : I checked the Event log . Under Windows Logs > Application, I can see the message , service started successfully . However , the event logs added in the try-catch block aren't get displayed. Not sure if I am missing something.

I attached the service to Visual Studio for debugging. In the below image, the `OnStart()` method is called. I just added the `Thread.Sleep(30000)` so that I get some buffer time to attach the process to the debugger to avoid skipping the `OnStart()` function

[image]

After the Timer starts, I have a breakpoint on the TimerTick() function expecting it to be hit, but it never does

[image]

Comment: you did wait long enough? stupid question maybe but you'll never know:)

Comment: Try to initialize with a lower interval and put a try\catch inside the timer1_Tick, logging the exception if it occurs.

Comment: @MartinoBordin I reduced the interval to 5 seconds and added a try-catch block, but I am not getting an emails .

Comment: Not getting emails doesn't mean the timer1_Tick method is not called.

Comment: Maybe change timer1_Tick function to  private void timer1_Tick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e). Even though very unlikely this is the cause, but give it a try?

Answer (score 2):

`timer1_Tick` is likely being called as everything in your `OnStart` seems appropriate. Perhaps the reason you aren't receiving e-mails is because `_SendEmail` is throwing the exception.

Writing to the `EventLog` might provide more information?

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SendMail._SendMail("Processing A started at" + DateTime.Now.ToString());
        Logging.log.LogInput("start refund process");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        EventLog.WriteEntry(ex.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error);
    }
}
```

As a best practice I would also write to the `EventLog` in `OnStart` and `OnStop`.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    // Log a service start message to the Application log.
    EventLog.WriteEntry("My Service in OnStart.");

    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(50000);
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer1_Tick);
    timer.Start();
}

protected override void OnStop()
{
    // Log a service stop message to the Application log.
    EventLog.WriteEntry("My Service in OnStop.");
}
```

Comment: I added the event logs as you suggested  . I even added them in the try block but the event viewer doesn't display any message. It shows that service started successfully but nothing after that.

Comment: @AnanthKumble Your issue isn't in the code you've provided. I created a simple service with nothing in it but the timer and it works as expected. Does your service stay running, perhaps it's crashing?

Comment: the service continues to stay running. Even I created a different  Window Service project and the timer function was called as expected. I am trying to fix the issue in an existing window service project